# How to split a file using awk based on a certain column value?

Tags: awk, split

I have a data file that contain something like:

data.txt:

```
AGG_KEY|Name|Product|Amount
CLASS01|Person1|Product A|100.00
CLASS01|Person2|Product A|200.00
CLASS02|Person1|Product B|100.00
CLASS03|Person2|Product B|400.00
CLASS03|Person2|Product C|500.00
CLASS03|Person3|Product D|600.00
```

I'm trying to split data.txt into data_CLASS01.txt, data_CLASS02.txt, data_CLASS03.txt, based on the AGG_KEY, and keeping the header line in each of the files.

The output file should be something like:

data_CLASS01.txt:

```
AGG_KEY|Name|Product|Amount
CLASS01|Person1|Product A|100.00
CLASS01|Person2|Product A|200.00
```

data_CLASS02.txt:

```
AGG_KEY|Name|Product|Amount
CLASS02|Person1|Product B|100.00
```

data_CLASS03.txt:

```
AGG_KEY|Name|Product|Amount
CLASS03|Person2|Product B|400.00
CLASS03|Person2|Product C|500.00
CLASS03|Person3|Product D|600.00
```

Any suggestion what would be the best way to achieve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
awk -F'|' '
    FNR == 1 { header = $0;next }
    !seen[$1]++ { print header > ("data_"$1".txt") }
    {
        print > ("data_"$1".txt");
    }
' data.txt
```

Comment: +1: Though worth mentioning that this will work only if the data is sorted as stated in the input (probably a non-issue). Also, you don't really need `>>` since you are not closing the file. Also, I would parenthesize the file name for portability. i.e `print header > ("data_"$1".txt")`

Comment: @jaypal: Thanks for the point. For the first, still thinking I'm in the shell instead of `awk`, fixed it. For the second, don't know about that, can you give some refereneces.

Comment: Sure, you can read about it [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Print). `The parentheses are necessary if any of the item expressions uses the ‘>’ relational operator; otherwise it could be confused with an output redirection (see Redirection).` If the `$1` happens to include such character then the solution might just break. So it's a good practice to always parenthesis it.

Comment: I have added a fix for un-sorted input. If you feel the change was too radical, please feel to roll back.

Comment: That works well, Thanks! 1 more additional question, is it possible to read in the input filename to be used as the output filename instead of hardcoding it to "data_"?

Comment: @jellyfizz: Of course. You can use `-v` option to create variable before processing, like `-v pre="data_" -v ext=".txt"`, then use `print > (pre $1 ext)`